# Does the word "but" sound odd here?

Tags: word-choice

I'm being influenced by another language, which is why this might sound so natural to me.  Still, I wonder what others would think about sentences like these.

"I realized it when we were shopping earlier, but you have really good taste in clothing."

Is the "but" in that sentence awkward?

Comment: *But* has to express some sort of contrast or negation; this would make more sense if you said "I only realized it ... but" or "I never realized before ... but".

Answer (score 2):

I would say *but* does sound awkward here. *But* is often used as *however*, to introduce a different, and often opposing, thought.

E.g.

> I realized it when we were shopping earlier, but I didn't tell you then. You have really good taste in clothing.

Proper uses of *but*:

He stumbled *but* didn't fall.
I am clean *but* you are dirty.
I'm enjoying myself immensely, *but* I must leave or I'll be late for work.

Comment: I hope you won't say [but me no buts](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but_me_no_buts), but I think you've got one too many "buts" in your third-to-last line. It would be *very* unusual to stack two consecutive contrasting "buts" in series like that, whatever the preceding context that we don't have.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Formatting problem. eliminated (with thanks.)

Comment: But I'll leave the comment there (it may help anyone who wants to get more familiar with how we might use the word "but" :)